# How to check if input string value contains x elements on the right and x elements on left

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a catch exception for input string for example

if user enters

```
123test456
```

the program to say

```
The first 3 characters must be letter
```

so it should accept

```
wowTest456
```

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"^\d{3}"))`

Comment: thank you it worked if i want to make the right side too do i change the / only?

Comment: To ensure the first and last 3 characters are not digits you could use the pattern `(^\d{3})|(\d{3}$)`.

Comment: What if there are only two characters? `ab` -> expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Take()`, with `.All()` including letter condition,

```
var validString = inputString
      .Take(3)
      .All(x => Char.IsLetter(x));
```

---

You can solve it using `Regex` too. Credit to [@JohnathanBarclay.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8126362/johnathan-barclay)

```
bool isInvalidString = Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^\d{3}");
```

Explanation:

- `^` : Matches the beginning of the string
- `\d`: Matches the digit characters
- `{3}` : Matches 3 tokens.

To make it positive regex just check `\w` instead of `\d`

```
bool validString = Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^\w{3}");
```

Using `\w` includes `_`(underscore) as well, if you don't want `_` as a part of first three letters, then you can use range like below

```
bool validString = Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3}");
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uO4dNa)

Comment: The trick here (before edited) used is that `char` can be compared as `int` and `a-z` `A-Z` are consecutive numbers, hence one can do this in C#. Char also has a `bool IsLetter()`.

Comment: This assumes the string is more than 3 characters long.

Comment: `If count exceeds the number of elements in source, all elements of source are returned.` , said on [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Not my point; should `"ab"` be considered valid?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, yes. I added fiddle and included small string as a scenario. You can try it.

Comment: The OP posted that the program should say `The first 3 characters must be letter`, but in the case of `"ab"` there are only 2 characters. Should this be valid? (I don't know)

Comment: Let just ask and get answer from OP